# Matplotlib pcolormesh, separate datacolor and color brightness information

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I would like to plot data on grid with matplotlib and am currently trying pcolormesh.
The data is organized in two numpy arrays, the data itself and a colorInformation array.

The code below plots the data array (1's are red and 0's are blue), however I also have the colorInformation array that should change the brightness of each corresponding cell square depending on its value, while keeping the color.

For example, the row [1, 0, 0, 1] from data should have the brightness values [0.1, 0.12, 0.02, 0.01] applied to it for the plot such that the row would visualize as [red and brightness 0.1, blue and brightness 0.12, blue and brightness 0.02, red and brightness 0.01]

How can this be accomplished?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1], 
                 [0, 0, 1, 1], 
                 [0, 0, 0, 1]])
colorInformation = np.array([[0.1, 0.12, 0.02, 0.01], 
                             [0.12, 0.15, 0.18, 0.2], 
                             [0.3, 0.34, 0.41, 0.32]])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
heatmap = ax.pcolormesh(data)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest making you own customized colormap to solve this problem

```
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
data = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1], 
                 [0, 0, 1, 1], 
                 [0, 0, 0, 1]])
colorInformation = np.array([[0.1, 0.12, 0.02, 0.01], 
                             [0.12, 0.15, 0.18, 0.2], 
                             [0.3, 0.34, 0.41, 0.32]])
alpha_up=abs(((data*2-1)*colorInformation).max())
alpha_low=abs(((data*2-1)*colorInformation).min())
mid=alpha_low/(alpha_up+alpha_low)
cdict1 = {'red':   ((0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
                   (mid, 1.0, 0.0),
                   (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),

         'green': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                   (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),

         'blue':  ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                   (mid, 0.0, 1.0),
                   (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)),

         'alpha':  ((0.0, alpha_low, alpha_low),
                   (mid, 0.0, 0.0),
                   (1.0, alpha_up, alpha_up))
        }
red_blue = LinearSegmentedColormap('red_blue', cdict1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
heatmap = ax.pcolormesh((data*2-1)*colorInformation, cmap=red_blue)
```

[image]

Or you can just change the red and blue and don't use the alpha channel.